# Should I always close a db post-request ( mongo db )

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and am wondering rather or not I am intended to use db.close() after every execution, or can I leave it open for the entire application's runtime.

To be more specific, I am running a chat application and for several events will read from and write to the database for room joins, leaves, logins, logouts, etc. When I perform the r/w do i need to close it on callback, or leave it open until the application is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using one DB connection then it is advised to reuse it across your application. In your case, if you are having all of your collections in a single DB you can reuse one single connection.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is actually a connection per chat server, which could be no more than 4 servers ( one main server, 3 foreign located servers ), but it doesn't scale further than that.

Comment: If you have parallel queries, you should use more than one connection